# Suspicious Gmail and Google Docs access

Tags: gmail, google-drive

For some time now, I'm noticing that a few of my Google Docs get accessed, yet I'm not accessing them myself, and they're not shared. I made a point of watching one of these documents and not touching it in any way, to see if it get accessed. Sure enough, it did get accessed.

I also noticed something similar in Gmail - a conversation that was marked as read, suddenly became marked as unread, even though I don't see any suspicious activity in the activity report that I get by clicking on the "Details" link at the bottom-right of the page.

Is this a known issue? Or should I be worried?

Comment: What third-party apps or add-ons are you using? What other sites have some sort of access to your account? Do you access Gmail in different places, such as on two different computers, browsers, or from a smartphone?

Comment: @AlE., I do access Gmail from different places (computers and phones) using only the official Google client, don't have any third party apps or add-ons, and I only use the Google account with other sites for log in purposes (I log in to StackExchange for example using my Google account). To access Google Docs, I don't use anything other than docs.google.com.

Comment: Follow the instructions of [Gmail Security Checklist - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/checklist/2986618?hl=en)

Comment: Yeah, I'd check that you don't have any apps with access that you don't know about, and change your password. This might be helpful too: [How do I protect my Google/Gmail account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51912/354)