# Suspicious device activity on Google Account

Tags: google-account, security

In a bit of an odd situation here. the password I use for my Gmail is unique and much stronger than other passwords I use as I consider my Gmail a high priority. I also have two-step authentication enabled to weed out any unwanted access. I checked the account activity on my Google Account and I noticed this;

[image: access from UK and US]

I'm from the UK, and yes my phone is a HTC One, but it's showing that the same device was accessed from the United States? - 2 hours ago! If it was a different HTC One, would it show as a separate HTC One or would it join them together? I also am starting to believe that Google's device activity is having some issues as I also noticed the following:

[image: access from Linux]

Now, I specifically recall a late night when I was up at 3:40AM, and that was me, but it's showing as Linux? Could anyone give me any information on what is going on here? I also see no other suspicious activity from my account it's just that device activity.

Comment: The Android oddness could easily be ascribed to an app that acts as a proxy. Which app that is, though, I couldn't tell you. For the Linux connection, that's an odd one. I suggest you check your [connected apps and sites](https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps) to make sure there's nothing there you're not expecting.

Comment: @AlE. I checked my connected apps and the only thing listed is Google Chrome, Pushbullet, & now stackexchange, I rarely use pushbullet anymore so I doubt it was that.. I forgot to mention, with the 'United States' I saw yesterday but thought nothing of it, until I saw again today it was recently accessed, it could be an app so I'm going to open various apps I've used today and see if anything changes. Thanks for the info though :)

Comment: Any one-time password for your 2-step auth? Might want to revoke those.

Comment: Already did that a few days ago

Comment: Then the only other thing I can suggest is to change your password. You might also find some useful advice here: [How do I protect my Google/Gmail account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51912/354)