# How to manage repeated notifications of attempts to hack into my account

Tags: google-account, security

Someone is repeatedly trying to gain access into my account. I have received 20 to 30 notifications of failed attempts of logging in. How do I stop them from continuing to try? They must have a program that is guessing and trying to log into my Google mail account. Its happening every 3-6 minutes for the past couple of days.

Comment: I would hope that Google would act to block that IP address/block of addresses/client quicker than a couple of days.

Comment: Also, be careful not to click links in those messages. They themselves may be phishing attempts. See: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6063333

Comment: "20 to 30 notifications of failed attempts" - what form does this "notification" take? Can you post an example/screenshot?

Answer (score 9):

You really can't stop them from trying but you can make your account more secure.  For GMail / Google account I would setup the 2 step authentication.  The 2 step process links your smartphone to your account so when you log in and get through, google will also send you a pin to your smartphone from which you will then verify.  Much more secure.

Comment: This may also be useful: [How do I protect my Gmail/Google account?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51912/354)

Answer (score 3):

1. Set up 2-Step verification.
2. Go to security settings and activity log. Note down the IP address of suspicious attempts. If all are different locations then someone is using a proxy. If not different, try reverse tracing it to get the ISP. You can also contact your cyber crime division in your country with these details in hand.