# Mysterious and unwanted filter in Gmail

Tags: gmail-filters

I am getting quotes from furniture removal companies. Every email with the word 'removal' in the subject line is being filtered directly to the trash/ bin. But I have not set up a filter for this to happen (obviously not - I'm trying to get the quotes!); and no filter to show this is listed in the filter section of 'settings' (otherwise I could just edit it out). Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is to remove the filter.

It sounds like something you may have added to address spam. Strings like "to request removal" are pretty common in spam messages.

There is a chance that your account is compromised. You should, of course, check to ensure that your account is not being accessed from somewhere it shouldn't be and that you haven't given access to apps that shouldn't be there.

See also: [How do I protect my Google/Gmail account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51912/354)

Comment: Adding filters is a very common tactic for an attacker to use when they gain access to a compromised Gmail account. If you ever find an unknown filter in your Gmail account I recommend resetting your password immediatly. The Gmail security checklist (https://support.google.com/mail/checklist/2986618?hl=en)  is a great resource for ensuring your Gmail account is secure.

Comment: @Folk: Sure, but that seems to be an odd filter to add. I'd think they'd do things like "Never send to spam" and "Mark important".

Comment: I agree. The filters I've seen on compromised accounts tend to send everything to Trash. My guess is these accounts are used to send phishing emails and the attackers don't want the user to see the responses. This is probably more common with Google Apps accounts because then the phishing messages are coming from someone else within your company. Admittedly it's unlikely to be what's happening to Offa however others finding this article may find it applies to them.