# How did this strange secondary Gmail account get created?

Tags: gmail, google-account, security, account-management

I've received an automated mail saying "my" new e-mail address was created. My e-mail is `example@gmail.com`, and the message says the new address is something like `exampleabc@gmail.com`.

I immediately changed the password and went through the security check. I also checked the latest activity. I saw something strange:

```
Authorized app (427071021612.apps.googleusercontent.com) 
Hide details
OAuth domain name:
427071021612.apps.googleusercontent.com
Manage account access
```

Why did this happen? Did I get hacked?

Comment: Was there a message at the bottom of the email alerting you to steps you can take if you received the message in error?

Comment: Yes, I followed the link to some Google page. Then I unlinked that bogus account from mine, then changed the password, then performed the security step-by-step process Google suggests. Then I turned on 2-step verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that more than likely someone created a new Gmail (Google) account and listed your email address as the account recovery email address. Why? Who knows. Error. Prank. Plain stupidity. Take your pick.

Your account is fine; this is little more than an inconvenience and, honestly, poor security on their part. Now you have a gateway to take over *their* account.

Another possibility is that this is a phishing message to try to get you to log into a bogus site and give up your credentials. As long as your [practicing good security to keep your Google account secure](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/51912/354) you should be fine. At the very least, be sure to use 2-step authentication.

Answer (score -3):

This number seems to relate to IFTTT (If This Then That, ifttt.com).

Your account is fine.

Comment: Please add a source that support your answer.