# Where can I see login attempts to Google account?

Tags: google-account

Where can I see login attempts to Google account?

I remember in the past soemtimes Google would send an automatic email if there was a login attempt from an unknown device and I think it would give a link to review activity, different login attempts, and I could device if the login attempts were suspicious.  I don't know if I imagined that such a link existed.

Now though I see an email about login attempt (one i did from a google chrome incognito window on my regular device!) .. but I see no way to review a list of login attempts.

If I go to https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity

I see https://myaccount.google.com/security?hl=en

It only shows me the last login attempt that google thought was suspicious

Is there a way to list login attempts?

I'm not sure if I imagined it or if Google removed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a warning if someone try to hack my Gmail account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/how-can-i-get-a-warning-if-someone-try-to-hack-my-gmail-account)

Comment: @BlindSpots First of all that question is very different from my one(and you should preface your comment with the remark that it's quite a different question. Secondly, one of the answers that is closest, is one showing successful login attempts.

Comment: The comment's specific text is automatically generated by the site when a reviewer suggests a question might be a duplicate.

Comment: @BlindSpots   I'm not talking about that. The description of the link is accurate as per the title of the question. (which is why, keeping that good automatically put in title description, you could preface that. Preface doesn't mean replace). And it's obviously not a duplicate, since my question is asking "where can I see login attempts" and that question is asking about warnings re a hacking attempt. Totally different question. That's not to say that there may be some relevants in a part of one answer, with my question, but it's clearly not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, let's discuss this in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/146753/blindspots-and-barlop) as comments are ill-suited.

Answer (score 0):

#### You Can't

Your Google account's ["Recent security activity"](https://myaccount.google.com/notifications) page doesn't include failed login attempts.

> It shows me the last login attempt that Google thought was suspicious

To be clear, the ["Recent security activity"](https://myaccount.google.com/notifications) page lists certain types of high-risk account activity from the last 28 days, not so much because they are necessarily suspicious in and of themselves, but because they can have serious consequences if they were not in fact performed by the account owner.

These include:

- Sign-ins on new devices
- Password changes
- Recovery info changes
- Requests to download your data

Also note that all these account activities are impossible unless already authenticated (logged in).

#### Organization Admins Can<sup>*</sup>

Organizations that have a Google Workspace subscription<sup>*</sup> can have their Admin generate a ["User login attempts report"](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9039184?hl=en) that includes failed logins.

<sup>*</sup> *Included with Enterprise Essentials Plus and up.*

Answer (score -2):

To access your account's recent activity, follow these steps:

1. Open Gmail.
2. Click on the "Details" option located at the bottom right corner.

Additionally, you can review recent security events by visiting the following page: https://myaccount.google.com/notifications.

Comment: The link you suggest, doesn't show it. Going to https://myaccount.google.com/notifications  (the link you wrote) shows https://i.stack.imgur.com/RewI0.png